# How to validate image on upload?

Tags: php, file, validation, image-processing, form-submit

I am playing around with some code and am wondering if both of these are needed?

I would think that if I have checked that it is an image then I would not need to verify if a correct extension is being used.

It seems redundant, but I may not be seeing the bigger picture.

```
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

I will be resizing and possibly changing the extension, that way I don't have to store it in the database.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. The extension isn't always correct. Testing if it actually is an image would be more reliable.

Comment: Well, if you omit the second bit, and someone uploads a TIFF, it will lie and tell them a TIFF is not an image ;(

Comment: @WheatBeak, I just tested a TIFF and it came back as an image

Comment: But do you want to allow TIFFs?

Comment: Continuing off of WheatBeak's comment. If you just want to check if the file is an image, then the 1st code block is sufficient, but if you only want to allow certain extensions (as in your case it seems), then you'll need the 2nd code block.

Comment: @WheatBeak, didn't think about and no I don't so I do need both.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly mentioned in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) not to use `getimagesize` for image validation.

> Caution getimagesize expects filename to be a valid image file. If a
>   non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image
>   and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain
>   nonsensical values. Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given
>   file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the
>   Fileinfo extension instead.

So you need few more checks regarding the file mime type, for further digging into this scenario I looked into Codeignitor code. Go to [this](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/fced25f5728ce81fe810216fcaa4ccec7523f6c9/system/libraries/Upload.php) link and look into the function named `_file_mime_type` here they detect file mime type and later they match with allowed file mime types.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix that: getimagesize